# Can't rename slug

Tags: entries, entry, slug, saveentry

Each time I try to rename a slug within an entry, the page refreshes, but the slug is getting a `-1` appended.

The slug I want is: `forms`. The slug I get after saving is: `forms-1`.

I've checked through all the other entries and there's no duplicate slug.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im pretty sure that craft will do this by default since you aren't using a dynamic slug like `{title}` or `{id}`

Comment: But I _can_ manually update the slug to `forms-something-else`, but not just `forms`.

Comment: Is forms the name of the section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to your database and run:

```
SELECT * FROM craft_elements_i18n WHERE slug = 'forms';
```

to see what other element is already using the slug `forms`.

To see what type of element it is (Entry, Asset, etc.), cross reference the `elementId` column of the result with the `id` column in the `craft_elements` table.

Comment: Note: If you're using Craft 3, the table you need to search it "craft_elements_sites". So the query would be `SELECT * FROM craft_elements_sites WHERE slug = 'forms';`